# How to sort get_terms() results in a specific order

Tags: arrays, wordpress, sorting

I am populating an unordered list by the results from get_terms() assigned to a variable. What I would like to do is order the results in a specific order in the unordered list. How would I do this? I looked into using the orderby argument for the get_terms() function but none of the parameters for that seem to work the way I need them to. How do I define a specific order for them to be displayed in? So basically my unordered list looks like this once populated:

- Atletics
- Community
- Corporate
- Healthcare
- Higher Education
- k-12

And I want it to look like this:

- k-12
- higher education
- healthcare
- atletics
- Corporate
- community

Comment: What is the basis for your desired ordering?

Comment: @MikeBrant client request

Comment: I mean by what logic are they ordered?  They are not in alphabetic order or any other logical means for ordering that I can tell. If you are looking for a hard-coded order, rather than a programmatic way to order, then you will have to hard-code it.

Comment: @MikeBrant yes. there is no logic to the order it is just what they would prefer. Which is why I was having a hard time finding a solution. The problem is my unordered list is being dynamically populated by the results from get_terms() so I am not sure how to hard code the order?

Comment: You would have to build a custom sort function to sort the list by the known terms (if any ones are retrieved that you don't have hard-coded rules for, perhaps they sort to the end). Alternately you could manually change the id's to your preferred sort order and sort by id.

Comment: Write a wrapper function for `get_terms` and then use `usort` to sort the terms

Answer (score 5):

The best option is to write a wrapper function for `get_terms` and then use `usort()` to sort the terms in the order you want.

Here is the code, I have commented the code to make it easy to follow and to understand (***NOTE:*** This code requires PHP 5.4+)

```
function get_terms_ordered( $taxonomy = '', $args = [], $term_order = '', $sort_by = 'slug' )
{
    // Check if we have a taxonomy set and if the taxonomy is valid. Return false on failure
    if ( !$taxonomy )
        return false;

    if ( !taxonomy_exists( $taxonomy ) )
        return false;

    // Get our terms    
    $terms = get_terms( $taxonomy, $args ); 

    // Check if we have terms to display. If not, return false
    if ( empty( $terms ) || is_wp_error( $terms ) )
        return false;

    /** 
     * We have made it to here, lets continue to output our terms
     * Lets first check if we have a custom sort order. If not, return our
     * object of terms as is
     */
    if ( !$term_order )
        return $terms;

    // Check if $term_order is an array, if not, convert the string to an array
    if ( !is_array( $term_order ) ) {
        // Remove white spaces before and after the comma and convert string to an array
        $no_whitespaces = preg_replace( '/\s*,\s*/', ',', filter_var( $term_order, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING ) );
        $term_order = explode( ',', $no_whitespaces );
    }

    // Remove the set of terms from the $terms array so we can move them to the front in our custom order
 $array_a = [];
 $array_b = [];
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        if ( in_array( $term->$sort_by, $term_order ) ) {
            $array_a[] = $term;
        } else {
            $array_b[] = $term;
        }
    }

    /**
     * If we have a custom term order, lets sort our array of terms
     * $term_order can be a comma separated string of slugs or names or an array
     */
    usort( $array_a, function ( $a, $b ) use( $term_order, $sort_by )
    {
        // Flip the array
        $term_order = array_flip( $term_order );

        return $term_order[$a->$sort_by] - $term_order[$b->$sort_by];
    });

    return array_merge( $array_a, $array_b );
}
```

There are four parameters to the function

- `$taxonomy` This is the taxonomy from which to get terms from. Default: empty string
- `$args` This is all the valid arguments that can be passed to `get_terms`. You can check out [`get_terms` for valid arguments](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms#Possible_Arguments). Default: empty array
- `$term_order` The slugs or names or ids of the terms in the specific order you want them sorted. This can be an array of slugs/names/ids or a comma separated string of slugs/names/ids. Default empty string

  Examples

  ```
  string: $term_order = 'term-3, term-1, term-2';
  array:  $term_order = ['term-3', 'term-1', 'term-2'];
  ```

  This will display the terms in order of `term-3, term-1, term-2`
- `$sort_by` By which field the terms must be sorted. The default value is slugs, so this means that you should pass a string or an array of terms slugs to the `$term_order` parameter. If you need to pass term names to the `$term_order` parameter, then you need to set the value of `$sort_by` to `name`. You can also pass, if you wish, term ids to `$term_order`, in which case you then need to set the `$sort_by` value to `term_id`

### USAGE

In your template, you will use the function as follow with the following example

Taxonomy name is `category`, we don't want to set any specific argument, we need sort the terms by name in the following order `Term C, Term A, Term B`

You will then do the following: (*`$term_order` as an array*)

```
$terms = get_terms_ordered( 'category', [], ['Term C', 'Term A', 'Term B'], 'name');
var_dump( $terms);
```

(*`$term_order` as a string*)

```
$terms = get_terms_ordered( 'category', [], 'Term C, Term A, Term B', 'name');
var_dump( $terms);
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer AND have a ton of upvotes, amazing answer.

Answer (score 2):

One problem I've found with setting an order that the client wants, is that the client will later want to re-order the list so another way to allow a desired order and ability to alter that later without adjusting the code would be the following:

1. Create a custom field for the taxonomy terms.  A great way is using Advanced Custom Fields plugin which makes this field editable in the dashboard.
2. Give that custom field a default value of '0'.
3. Use the `get_terms()` function and include the following settings in the array.  In this example `jht_order` is the name of the custom field.

```
'orderby'  => 'meta_value',
'meta_key' => 'jht_order',
```

Now the terms will be ordered by the value of this field.  Note: if the term doesn't have this field populated, it won't be returned by `get_terms()`

Update: If the custom field is a number, you'll want to change 'orderby' to be 'meta_value_num' so it will sort it as a number and not as ascii.

```
'orderby'  =>  'meta_value_num'
```

Comment: I like this solution giving the client can set the order